# Navbar and footer gets rendered all time

Tags: reactjs

```
function AppWrapper() {


  return (
   <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
 
 
      <div className="flex-1">
        <Navbar />
      <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/cart" element={<Cartlist />} />
            <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout/>}/>
          
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
            <Route path="/head" element={<Commondetail propName="head"/>} />
            <Route path="/ear" element={<Commondetail propName="ear"/>} />
            <Route path="/speak" element={<Commondetail  propName="speak"/>} />
            <Route path="/product"  >
            <Route path=':id' element={<Product />} />

            </Route>
            <Route path="/user/*" element={<Userpage />}>
  <Route path="updatepassword" element={<Updatepassword />} />
</Route>
          
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
      </div>

    
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppWrapper />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Hello all my navbar and footer gets re-renders all the time.I need to keep navbar and footer static while others should render.Now during each transition i am getting white screen then only it renders

Comment: useLocation triggers rerender on route change. Remove it if you don't need it or move the logic to a separated component. Or you can always use React.memo

Comment: @OktayYuzcan hey i removed it still the re rendeing exist

Comment: That means there is something in the code, that does not exist in the question. If you put an empty component outside of the Routes and track for its updates, you will find out whether the AppWrapper or your Navbar and Footer have problems